# Functional testing of canvas js chart

Tags: protractor, sikuli

I am trying to do functional testing of a web app built using angular 5. The appln contains a lot of canvas js based charts. I have to check the mouse over values within the canvas images and also the inner text and compare it to the sql server query in the backend to see if they are properly populated. I am currently using protractor and able to hover over the element but not get the value within the hover. Can someone suggest a way to do this - using protractor or any other tool. I am wondering if this is even possible. There is no data populated in the DOM for the canvas object or the tool tip.the chart is similar to this- I need to get the inner textt value and the mouse over values. All these are dynamically generated based on a drop down selection in ui[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3pOZ.jpg)

```
    <canvas _ngcontent-c13="" chartjs="" height="159" width="319" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; height: 199px; width: 399px;">
        </canvas>
```

[added canvas html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syV0X.png)

Comment: Does tooltip element appears in the DOM? You can ask the developer to add attribute with needed data for you.

Comment: You should create a small example which reproduces your problem. Let a canvas draw on the page and copy all html from it. With given html you'll just have to write correct locator.

Comment: @SilvanBregy: not sure I understand what you are saying.. could you please elaborate? Do you mean to say that I have to draw the canvas element again in the protractor code? can you please help me with a sample code of what you are saying..I am completely new to javascript and protractor

Comment: @user9919998 I just wanted to explain what always to do when working with protractor. In your case, you have to check the onHover value. Everything you can see on the page has to be stored within the html somewhere. So I usually just set the page in a state, where my data which I want to check is visible. I afterward just copy the html and search for the value I wanna check. As I have found it , next step is just to create a `by.css()` selector for it and check it.  It's not the best english ~>)

Comment: Ok .. sorry the hover values are not available on the html.. anyone has used hooks to do something similar ? If so can you please help me with a sample code ?